# Обновляемый регион при перерисовке окна по WM_PAINT

Tags: winapi

Как при перерисовке окна по WM_PAINT получить обновляемый регион. То есть регион который становится видимым при изменении размеров (при только уменьшении он не должен появляться), при перемещении других окон на данным, при прокрутке и так далее. Предполагается что остальныя часть окна содержит неизменное изображение и не нуждается в перерисовке.

Проблема в том, что я получаю только весь видимый прямоугольник. Код стандартный:

```
 switch(message)
 {
 case WM_PAINT:
 {
      PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};
      auto hdc = ::BeginPaint(window, &ps);
      const auto bounds = ps.rcPaint; // здесь весь фрейм
      const auto dirty  = ???
      ::EndPaint(window, hdc);
 }
 break;

 case WM_SIZE:
 break;

 default:
    return DefWindowProc(window, message, wparam, lparam);
 }
 return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Для получения обновляемого региона нужно использовать функцию GetUpdateRgn (вызывать ее нужно **до вызова** BeginPaint).

Для полноты картины можно еще упомянуть функцию GetUpdateRect, которая возвращает ограничивающий прямоугольник обновляемого региона.

Comment: На всяк случай + `PtInRegion`

Comment: @freim вопрос изменился

Comment: @Cerbo, ответ тот же самый. Вас в этом ответе что-то не устроило или непонятно? Что именно?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь в том, что при получении `WM_SIZE` возвращается 0. То есть системе сообщается что сообщение обработано, тогда как на самом деле ничего не сделано. Разработчики WinAPI видимо решили здесь соптимизировать по логике, что раз `WM_SIZE` обработано, то и регион обновления вычислять не надо.

Наиболее правильно здесь по `WM_SIZE` возвращать результат `DefWindowProc`. То есть просто убрать эту пустую ветку для `WM_SIZE`. Вот так работает, регион обновления вычисляется:

```
switch(message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
{
          auto dirty        = ::CreateRectRgn(0,0,0,0);
    const auto dirty_status = ::GetUpdateRgn(window, dirty, FALSE);
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};
        auto hdc = ::BeginPaint(window, &ps);
        const auto dirty_bounds = ps.rcPaint;
        ::EndPaint(window, hdc);
    }
    ::DeleteObject(dirty);
}
break;

//case WM_SIZE:
//break;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Правильнее было бы дополнить вопрос, а не писать это как ответ. Не совсем понятна проблема все же. Вы пишете: "*Проблема здесь в том, что при получении WM_SIZE возвращается 0*". Звучит как если бы кто-то другой это возвращал, а не вы. Это же вы, программист, сообщаете системе, обработало ваше приложение WM_SIZE или нет.

Comment: А в том, что система не вычисляет регион обновление если приложение само обрабатывает WM_SIZE, есть вполне очевидный резон. Представим, что вы пишете текстовый редактор, и нужно обработать увеличение окна. Если перенос строк (word wrap) выключен, достаточно отрисовать новую часть окна. Если включен, текст нужно полностью переформатировать, и перерисовывать придется окно целиком. У системы просто нет достаточной информации, чтобы определить регион обновления и оптимизация тут не при чем.